macOS incorrectly computing available SSD space
I noticed the other day that my M2 MacBook Air with 1TB of storage was showing less space available under System Settings than I expected I was using.
After thoroughly combing through my files, and checking with both CleanMyMac X and Disk Inventory X, it appears as if the drive may be miscalculating its usage. For example, see the below image of Disk Inventory X. In the top section of the image you can see the drive reports that 762.8 GB has been used. After opening it (bottom of the image), you can see that it Disk Inventory X only catalogs 326.0 GB worth of files.
In General > Storage, the bulk of this disk usage (623.25 GB) is listed as System Data.
One theory I had is that the delta here may be caused by the file ~/Library/iCloud Drive. In Finder, this file is being listed as the total size of all of the files I store in iCloud. However, only a subset of those files are actually downloaded onto my computer. Although when viewing the info of the file, it does say that the actual size is considerably less.
Even after moving over a hundred gigs files outside of iCloud Drive, which has reduced the size of the file, the space taken up by System Data under General>Storage has remained unchanged.
Rebooting the computer has not fixed it, and running First Aid in Disk Utility reported no issues.
Does anyone know what might be going on here?
My next steps would be to back up my computer to an external hard drive and then restore it from the image, though I would rather not if anyone has tips. I'm also not sure if this error would persist through a restore.
A few other details:

Time Machine is not enabled
There is only one user account on this computer
See below for images from Disk Utility






Do you have Time Machine enabled? // Also keep in mind that free space is shared across all filesystems in an APFS container.

Time Machine is not enabled. This computer only has one user, and Disk Utility doesn’t seem to suggest that there are other filesystems taking up space. I can add a screenshot of that if it would be useful.

Howard Oakley has a good article on how the Finder doesn't always give you the correct amount of actual space used. This may be what is going on here, I am not sure. What I am sure about is that Apple has somehow made getting accurate disk space readings problematic. https://eclecticlight.co/2024/05/08/how-accurate-are-the-finders-folder-and-volume-sizes/

Daisy Disk has much better understanding of current macOS disk usage than other disk space apps.

@Gilby thank you! That app was able to identify this as a backup from Arq. I can't believe only this app was able to find the file...thanks again dude.
